# Optimizar mi código en python (BUCLE)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

```
print("SISTEMA DE VENTAS - BODEGA TUTI")
def código():
  print("CODIGO DEL PRODUCTO Y PRECIO: \n A01 - ARROZ ->4.50 \n A02 - AZUCAR ->3.20 \n A03 - FIDEO ->3.10 \n A04 - LECHE ->2.50 \n A05 - ATUN ->6.50 \n A06 - TE ->1.20 \n A07 - HUEVO ->5.50 \n A08 - ACEITE ->8.00 \n A09 - COCOA ->2.00 \n A10 - ANIS ->1.20")

def vale():
  print("VALE: \n V1 ->5% \n V2 ->10% \n V3 ->20% \n V4 ->30% \n V5 -> GRATIS")

entrada=str(input("Ingresa A-B-C-D-E-F: "))
if entrada=="A" or "a":
  a=str(input("Ingresar Nombre y Apellido: "))
  codigo() 
  b=str(input("Ingresar Codigo y Producto: "))
  if b=="A01":
    s1=4.50
    c=int(input("Ingresar Cantidad: "))
    subtotal=c*s1
  elif b=="A02":
    s2=3.20
    c=int(input("Ingresar Cantidad: "))
    subtotal=c*s2
  elif b=="A03":
    s3=3.10
    c=int(input("Ingresar Cantidad: "))
    subtotal=c*s3
  elif b=="A04":
    s4=2.50
    c=int(input("Ingresar Cantidad: "))
    subtotal=c*4
  elif b=="A05":
    s5=6.50
    c=int(input("Ingresar Cantidad: "))
    subtotal=c*s5
  elif b=="A06":
    s6=1.20
    c=int(input("Ingresar Cantidad: "))
    subtotal=c*s6
  elif b=="A07":
    s7=5.50
    c=int(input("Ingresar Cantidad: ")) 
    subtotal=c*s7
  elif b=="A08":
    s8=8.00
    c=int(input("Ingresar Cantidad: ")) 
    subtotal=c*s8
  elif b=="A09":
    s9=2.00
    c=int(input("Ingresar Cantidad: ")) 
    subtotal=c*s9
  elif b=="A10":
    s10=1.20
    c=int(input("Ingresar Cantidad: "))   
    subtotal=c*s10


  vale()
  e=str(input("Ingresar vale Descuento: "))
  if e=="V1":
    v =0.05
  elif e=="V2":
    v =0.10
  elif e=="V3":
    v =0.20
  elif e=="V4":
    v =0.30
  elif e=="V5":
    v = 1

  print("IMPRESION DE LA BOLETA:")
  print("Cliente:",a)
  print("Producto:",b )
  print("Cantidad:",c)
  print("Descuento:",v )
  print("Total: ",subtotal)
elif entrada=="B" or "C" or "D" or "F" or "G":
  print("INCORRECTO: DEBES EMPEZAR CON A")
```

El propósito del código es elegir las letras de la `a` a la `g`, la `a` es para registrar el nombre y apellido, la `b` es para mostrar y elegir los productos. Una vez se elige en pantalla debe aparecer cual es la elección y guardarse. En la variable `c` es para ingresar la cantidad según la elección mediante el código ingresado. la `d` es el subtotal, es decir, la multiplicación de la cantidad por el precio del producto. La `e` es ingresar el valor y para aplicar un descuento. La `f` es para mostrar la boleta donde estaban registrados todos los datos que se pidieron (el total es el sub total con el descuento aplicado).

La cuestión es que si elijo una letra que no sea `a` ésta me debe decir que tengo que empezar por registrarme, es decir, desde la `a`.

Después de una elección de letras y de la inserción de datos debo regresar al menú y continuar con el siguiente proceso y asi sucesivamente. Éste es mi código, pero si le doy más `if` va a ser más largo y quisiera un apoyo para tener reducción de codigo y optimización de procesos.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad. Has creado una buena primer pregunta, con ejemplo y código, aún así permíteme recomendarte leer las secciones [ask] y [tour]. Por cierto, escribir con mayúsculas es interpretado como gritar y por lo tanto no es bien visto.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Lo que podrías hacer es utilizar un `while` para crear un ciclo infinito hasta que el usuario complete la secuencia en forma correcta y un `for` para revisar y comparar que cada entrada del usuario corresponda con la letra en el orden específico.

Si creas una variable con el orden que deseas la secuencia, por ejemplo:

```
orden = 'ABCDEF'
```

Podrías crear un `for` que itere el `orden` y en cada iteración pida la entrada del usuario, si el valor ingresado es igual al valor de la iteración de `orden` entonces continua. Si es diferente entonces el ciclo `for` debe reiniciarse.

Ejemplo simplificado que solicita ingresar la secuencia `ABCDEF`:

```
orden = 'ABCDEF'

while True:
    print('Ingresa A-B-C-D-E-F: ')
    for i in orden:
        opcion = input()
        if opcion != i:
            print('Secuencia incorrecta')
            # Salir del for y reiniciar el proceso
            break
        else:
            # Agregar lo que hay que hacer para cada opción
            continue
    if i == opcion == orden[-1]:
        print('Proceso finalizado')
        # Salir del while
        break
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
Ingresa A-B-C-D-E-F: 
 A
 F
Secuencia incorrecta
Ingresa A-B-C-D-E-F: 
 A
 B
 E
Secuencia incorrecta
Ingresa A-B-C-D-E-F: 
 A
 B
 C
 D
 E
 F
Proceso finalizado
```

**Nota adicional:** Yo agregaría la función de aceptar letras en mayúscula o minúscula para hacer el uso más amigable (Pero no sé si requieres únicamente mayúsculas) al utilizar `lower()`

Ejemplo:

```
orden = 'abcdef'

while True:
    print('Ingresa A-B-C-D-E-F: ')
    for i in orden:
        opcion = input()
        if opcion.lower() != i:
            print('Secuencia incorrecta')
            # Salir del for y reiniciar el proceso
            break
        else:
            # Agregar lo que hay que hacer para cada opción
            continue
    if i == opcion.lower() == orden[-1]:
        print('Proceso finalizado')
        # Salir del while
        break
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
Ingresa A-B-C-D-E-F: 
 a
 B
 c
 D
 e
 a
Secuencia incorrecta
Ingresa A-B-C-D-E-F: 
 a
 b
 C
 d
 E
 F
Proceso finalizado
```

Lo que tendrías que agregar es lo que el código tiene que hacer al ingresar cada opción. Esto lo puedes hacer al crear un `else` del `if` que está dentro del `for` ya que ese sería el escenario donde la opción ingresada y el orden coinciden.

Comment: COMO DICES SI ES NECESARIO EN MAYUSCULA Y MINUSCULA LA CUESTION ESTA EN QUE AUN NOSE DOMINAR LOS BUCLES DEBO USAR NO SOLO PARA ESA SENTENCIA SINO TAMBIEN PARA EL CODIGO DEL PRODUCTO

Comment: Por favor evita escribir en mayúsculas. En la respuesta he puesto el ejemplo para evaluar mayúsculas y el segundo ejemplo considera mayúsculas y minúsculas. De esta forma puedes evitar crear todos los `if` que tenías.

Comment: Para los más avanzados: El código del for se puede convertir a `all(input().lower() == i for i in orden)`. Esta linea de código devuelve True cuando todas las condiciones dan verdadero y False cuando alguna falla. Lo mejor es que automaticamente el iterable o iterador deja de ser recorrido cuando alguna de las condiciones da False.

Comment: @DanteS., en ese caso, cuando el input coincida con el orden, ¿Cómo se agregarían las acciones a realizar para cada opción? Según entendí, al ingresar `a` se debe realizar una tarea, luego al ingresar `b` otra y así. Con la línea como la pusiste creo que no se pueden realizar acciones por cada entrada de parte del usuario, únicamente revisa que se ingresen las letras de la "a" a la "f" en orden, ¿Es correcto?

Comment: En realidad, si. Pensé que no era necesario acceder a esos valores.

Comment: @DanteS. Esa alternativa es intolerante a errores de digitación.

Comment: Yo me base en un codigo que tambien es intolerante a errores de digitacion.

Answer (score 1):

`input` devuelve un string; no necesitas hacer `str(input())`.

Una parte horrible de tu código es esa larga serie de `if`:

```
  b=str(input("Ingresar Codigo y Producto: "))
  if b=="A01":
    s1=4.50
    c=int(input("Ingresar Cantidad: "))
    subtotal=c*s1
  elif b=="A02":
    s2=3.20
    c=int(input("Ingresar Cantidad: "))
    subtotal=c*s2
     ...
  elif b=="A10":
    s10=1.20
    c=int(input("Ingresar Cantidad: "))   
    subtotal=c*s10
```

En lugar de repetir el mismo código una y otra vez, usa un diccionario donde la llave sea el código del producto y su valor el precio del mismo:

```
t_prod = {
    "A01": 4.5,
    "A02": 3.2,
    ...
    "A10": 1.2
}
```

y reemplaza todos esos `if` por

```
  b=input("Ingresar Codigo y Producto: ")
  if b in t_prod:
      precio = t_prod[b]
      cantidad = int(input("Ingresar Cantidad: "))
      subtotal= precio * cantidad
```

Lo mismo vale para el vale de descuento:

e=input("Ingresar vale Descuento: ")
if e in t_vale:
v = t_vale[e]

donde `t_vale` es otro diccionario:

t_vale = {"V1" : 0.05, "V2": 0.10, "V3": 0.20, "V4": 0.30, "V5": 1}

Consejo: si tienes que escribir dos veces lo mismo, lo estas haciendo mal; busca una alternativa más corta.