# ¿Cómo verificar que lo que el usuario insertó es tiene una de dos palabras de la lista que tengo, pero además, sea en el orden que yo demando?

Tags: python

Deseo comparar el valor que inserta un usuario (str) con el valor que yo tengo en una variable.
Es decir, no solo ver que hay texto que se parece, sino comprobar que lo escribió de la forma correcta. Según la la escala descendente es.
Validando que no escribió la palabra primero, segundo, etc. Sino, comprobando que realmente escribió el nombre de las operaciones de forma correcta.

Fue una idea que me surgió para practicar condicionales, pero, pero se me ocurrieron distintas cosas que un usuario podría hacer, y tras ello estoy tratando de resolverlo.

Tengo una semana estudiando un curso de python.

El código es el siguiente.

```
import sys
import unicodedata


def consult(param):
    #dictionary replace char special
    mapeo = {ord(','): ''}

    param = str.casefold(param).translate(mapeo)

    # Convert char special in letter
    convert_char = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(
    sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.combining(chr(i)))

    param_normalize = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', param)

    param = param_normalize.translate(convert_char)

    print(param)

    hierarchy = "\
            La jerarquía de resolución de operaciones matemáticas, es 
     así:\n\n \
                Primero: Paréntesis \n \
            Segundo: Exponentes \n \
            Tercero: Multiplicación \n \
            Cuarto: Divisiones \n \
            Quinto: Sumas \n \
            Sexto: Restas \n \
            "
```

Hasta este punto lo que he hecho, es quitar comas, por sí se le ocurre al usuario, y convertir las letras con tildes a sin tildes

```
    def convert_hierarchy(hierarchy):
        print("- Vale, eso es genial. \n")

        question = str(input("- ¿Podrías decirme en orden descendente? 
        \n- "))
        question, hierarchy2 = question.casefold().replace(
            'parentesis', 'paréntesis'), hierarchy.casefold()

        hierarchy2 = hierarchy.casefold()

        #Convert and transform the text in question and hierarchy
        mapeo = {
                 ord(','): '',
                }

        question = question.translate(mapeo)
```

Esta es la parte en la que doy respuesta al usuario, dependiendo de lo que haya dicho

```
        if question in hierarchy2:
            print(f'\nWow, ¡Eres un pro! Ciertamente\n{hierarchy}')

        else:
            print(f'\nLo siento, te has equivocado.\n{hierarchy}')

    if (param == 'no'):

        print(hierarchy)

    elif (param == 'si'):
        # Send to function convert_hierarchy
        convert_hierarchy(hierarchy)
```

Ahora, este es el punto de partida y final del programa.

```
# First question
question = str(input('- ¿Recuerdas cómo es la jerarquía de resolución'
                     'en operaciones matemáticas?\n- '))

# Sending input to function consult
consult(question)
```

Comment: Buen día, no es claro lo que deseas lograr. El ejemplo no refleja lo mencionado en el texto y el texto menciona casos que no han sido ejemplificados. ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo completo de la entrada y lo que deseas hacer así como el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema?

Comment: Claro, lo voy a modificar, entonces

Comment: En general, lo que deseas es que el usuario escriba "Paréntesis", luego "Exponentes", luego "Multiplicación", luego "Divisiones", luego "Sumas" y por último "Restas" tal como están escritas en digamos tu plantilla y que sean exactamente en ese orden?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Sí, justamente así. Que el usuario los escriba en ese orden.
Pensé en hacer varios inputs, pero, pensé que podría haber algo más efectivo.

Answer (score 1):

Primero formemos una lista ordenada de operaciones:

```
hierarchy = ['parentesis', 'exponente', 'multiplicacion', 'division', 'suma', 'resta']
```

Las operaciones las escribimos en minúsculas, singular, sin acentos.

Tomamos la entrada del usuario y eliminamos todos los acentos y otros signos diacríticos usando `unidecode.unidecode(str)`, que recibe un string y lo retorna convertido a ascii (si se puede).

La entrada luego la convierto en una lista de palabras. Si está lista no mide lo mismo que lista oficial, se retorna de inmediato con resultado `False`.

Si ambas listas miden lo mismo, las recorro en orden, comparando lso respectivos elementos cada vez.

La comparación se hace considerando el largo de la respuesta válida. Por ejemplo, la respuesta correcta es "division", pero si el usuario dice "divisiones", sólo se comparan los 8 primeros caracteres.

Si se detecta una diferencia, se termina con `False`.

Si la iteración termina sin problemas, se retorna con `True`.

Demo

```
import unidecode

hierarchy = ['parentesis', 'exponente', 'multiplicacion', 'division', 'suma', 'resta']
answer = "parentesis, exponente, multiplicacion, sumas, restas, divisiones"

def validar(jerarquia, respuesta):
    #   Validar que ambas listas contengan la
    #   misma cantidad de palabras.
    respuestas = unidecode.unidecode(respuesta.lower()).split()
    if len(jerarquia) != len(respuestas):
        print("Distinto largo")
        return False

    #   Ambas listas del mismo largo,
    #   revisar que la secuencia sea la misma
    for i in range(len(jerarquia)):
        respuesta = ''.join(x for x in respuestas[i] if x.isalpha())
        if jerarquia[i] != respuesta[:len(jerarquia[i])]:
            print(f"{i} {jerarquia[i]} != {respuestas[i]}")
            return False
    return True

r = validar(hierarchy, answer)
print(f"Validación arroja {r}")
```

produce:

```
3 division != sumas,
Validación arroja False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Otra forma de resolverlo es utilizando un diccionario. Desde `Python 3.7` en adelante, los diccionarios respetan el orden de los elementos tal como fueron creados, si utilizas alguna versión anterior entonces tendrías que utilizar la sub clase `OrderedDict` del módulo `collections`.

Utilizando el módulo `unicodedata` podemos crear una función para normalizar las letras con acentos, y con la función `lower` podemos cambiar todo a minúsculas, por ejemplo las palabras `'François PaRéntesis'` quedarían así: `'francois parentesis'`

```
def convert_string(s):
    # Convierte los caracteres con acento al caracter similar sin acento y cada letra a minúsculas
    return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn').lower()
```

Ahora, el usuario podría ingresar la información de diferentes formas, una es como en la respuesta propuesta por @CandidMoe, que toda la respuesta sea un único `string` separado por comas. Otra forma sería que el usuario ingrese cada respuesta de forma individual en un `input` único para cada respuesta. Esta segunda forma es el enfoque que utilizo en la solución que propongo

La siguiente sección de código hace toda la magia:

```
all(convert_string(input()) == v for k,v in hierarchy.items())
```

Explicación:

La función `all` revisa que todos los elementos de un iterable sean verdaderos y devuelve `True` si así es, en caso contrario, es decir, si cualquiera de los elementos del iterable es `False` entonces devuelve `False` ([Lectura recomendada](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/funciones-any-y-all-en-python-explicadas-con-ejemplos/#:%7E:text=La%20funci%C3%B3n%20all()%20toma,los%20dem%C3%A1s%20casos%20retornara%20False%20.))

Adentro de `all` hay una expresión generadora ([Lectura recomendada](https://es.acervolima.com/comprensiones-de-listas-de-python-frente-a-expresiones-de-generador/)) que crea un iterable para que `all` lo evalue.

Cada elemento del iterable es una entrada del usuario, esa entrada del usuario primero se normaliza con la función descrita anteriormente y se compara con uno de los elementos de nuestra plantilla de respuestas `hierarchy` y al estar iterando el mismo diccionario `hierarchy` entonces se evalúa elemento por elemento y en el orden tal y como fueron creados dentro de `hierarchy`.

Para evaluar el sentido opuesto lo único que tenemos que hacer es invertir el diccionario, eso lo podemos hacer con la función `reversed`:

```
all(convert_string(input()) == v for k,v in reversed(hierarchy.items()))
```

Lo único que haría falta sería poner estas líneas en un `if` y toda la evaluación se hace correctamente.

Ejemplo:

```
import unicodedata

def convert_string(s):
    # Convierte los caracteres con acento al caracter similar sin acento y cada letra a minúsculas
    return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn').lower()

# Diccionario de respuestas
# A partir de Python 3.7 los diccionarios respetan el orden de los elementos
# tal como fueron creados, si utilizas una versión anterior tendrías que utilizar
# la sub clase `OrderedDict` del módulo `collections`
hierarchy = {'primero': 'parentesis',
             'segundo': 'exponentes',
             'tercero': 'multiplicaciones',
             'cuarto': 'divisiones',
             'quinto': 'sumas',
             'sexto': 'restas'}

# Revisa el orden ascendente
# items devuelve una relación llave valor
# all revisa que todas las entradas del usuario vayan en el orden indicado en el diccionario
# si alguna respuesta ingresada no es no es igual a los elementos de hierarchy
# o está en el orden incorrecto entonces devuelve False
if all(convert_string(input()) == v for k,v in hierarchy.items()):
    print('Orden correcto')
else:
    print('Orden incorrecto')

# Revisa el orden descendente al utilizar reversed
if all(convert_string(input()) == v for k,v in reversed(hierarchy.items())):
    print('Orden descendente correcto')
else:
    print('Orden descendente incorrecto')
```

Ejemplo de funcionamiento:

```
# Se ingresa cada respuesta en una entrada diferente
# Ejemplo del orden ascendente con todas las respuestas correctas
# Nota como no importa si hay acentos y/o mayúsculas
 Paréntesis
 expoNentes
 Multiplicaciones
 Divisiones
 sumas
 resTAS
Orden correcto
# Se evalua el orden descendente, el usuario empieza bien
# Si hay alguna entrada que no esté en nuestra plantilla
# como "no me acuerdo" o si no está en el orden correcto
# entonces `all` devuelve Falso
 restas
 sumas
 divisiones
 no me acuerdo
Orden descendente incorrecto
```

**Nota adicional y créditos:** Para la respuesta me basé en un comentario de @DanteS. que hizo en esta [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/558412/171630), ese comentario fue la inspiración para la respuesta.